# 'No bootable devices found' error while booting a Ubuntu only system (Dell Latitude 3480) with a USB mouse inserted while booting.

Tags: 16.04, boot, dell

I have a few months old Dell Latitute 3480 notebook with Ubuntu 16.04 (only, no windows) installed.

Today I was trying to boot the pc while having inserted a new usb mouse, during which the system gave an error of 'No bootable devices found'.

I tried to reboot several times, but with no success and I am stuck with my machine not starting. I would not like to format given all my data and software on the machine.

Any help?

Comment: Check your BIOS if the HDD/SSD detected or not. If detected, make it as the primary drive and check.

Comment: It is not detected. How do I make it detect the SSD?

Comment: It can be due to various problems, Since you are new to PC hardware and it is a notebook, i think its better you check with a hardware technician for the fix. As far as i know there is no fix we can do without removing the back cover of the notebook.

Comment: Don't know the Dell BIOS, but in some cases you have to struggle with 'legacy USB'  or 'legacy USB when booting'. As the mouse (without system driver) maybe only works with legacy USB, the BIOS may switch to that and so the disk is not recognized (as boot device).